# Matplotlib is plotting multiple labels

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I have matrix `A` of size `50x4` and another matrix `B` of size `4*2`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(np.dot(A, B), [0]*A.shape[0], "bo", label="Tennis")

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

How to make matplotlib display the label name only once?

Comment: I can't recreate this issue. Are you sure you aren't calling `plt.plot` again on a different data set (or the same data set) with the same label?

Answer (score 2):

Because you have 2 columns of data.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A=np.random.rand(50, 4)
B=np.random.rand(4, 2)
C=np.dot(A, B)
D=[0]*A.shape[0]
plt.plot(C, D, "bo", label="Tennis")

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

C has now shape (50, 2) and D has shape (50,)

```
>>> C.shape
(50, 2)
>>> np.shape(D)
(50,)
```

The Documentation on `plt.plot` says:

> If x and/or y is 2-dimensional, then the corresponding columns will be plotted.

I would recommend you to fix this by reducing the data to one column using `C.flatten()` and changing the dimension of `D` accordingly.